# SharePoint List lookup from Excel file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, excel-services

I would like to know, whether we can look up for a value in an excel file within a SharePoint list.

I know that we can setup look up within different lists within a site. But i would like to know, whether we can do it from an excel file(stored offline/online) to SharePoint list.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. Either import the spreadsheet to create a list or use Access 2010 to import the list into SharePoint.